# How do I create nested dictionary from pandas data frame while adding numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to create a nested dictionary with the key as the office, then the remaining columns added within that office.

Should look something like this.

final_dict = {'YELLOW': {'Files Loaded': 21332, 'Files Assigned': 10613} 'RED':....}....

Current code is and I'm completely stuck on how to nest and add the values.

```
d = {'Office': ['Yellow','Yellow','Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue'], 'Files Loaded': [1223, 3062, 10, 100, 1520, 75], 'Files Assigned': [1223, 30, 1500, 10, 75, 12],
     'Files Analyzed': [1223, 15, 25, 34, 98, 1000], 'Discrepancies Identified': [17, 30, 150, 1456, 186, 1896]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fields = ['Files Loaded', 'Files Assigned', 'Files Analyzed', 'Discrepancies Identified']

final_dict = df.groupby('Office')[fields].apply(list).to_dict()
print(final_dict)

{'Blue': ['Files Loaded', 'Files Assigned', 'Files Analyzed', 'Discrepancies Identified'], 'Red': ['Files Loaded', 'Files Assigned', 'Files Analyzed', 'Discrepancies Identified'], 'Yellow': ['Files Loaded', 'Files Assigned', 'Files Analyzed', 'Discrepancies Identified']}
```

Comment: You have duplicate entries in the original 'Office' list. If you wamt to have `Office` as a key in your final list, how do you plan to differentiate between two names being the same? (Note: Dictionaries can't have two or more keys with the same name.)

Comment: I am trying to add all the 'Files Loaded' for blue together (Same for all of them). So final dict would look like something like.
 {'YELLOW': {'Files Loaded': 21332, 'Files Assigned': 10613}... The numbers in there are the grand total for all 'Yellow' files loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following input:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

d = {'Office': ['Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Red', 'Blue', 'Blue'], 
     'Files Loaded': [1223, 3062, 10, 100, 1520, 75],
     'Files Assigned': [1223, 30, 1500, 10, 75, 12],
     'Files Analyzed': [1223, 15, 25, 34, 98, 1000], 
     'Discrepancies Identified': [17, 30, 150, 1456, 186, 1896]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

We can use the pandas `groupby` and aggregation (`agg`) function to sum up the totals per office. Then by using `to_dict` on `'index'`, we get the data provided as a dictionary, where the `key` is the `Office` and the values are a dictionary for which the `key` is the column name and the values are the aggregated count.

```
data = df.groupby('Office').agg('sum')
answer = data.to_dict('index')

pprint(answer)
```

Output:

```
{'Blue': {'Discrepancies Identified': 2082,
          'Files Analyzed': 1098,
          'Files Assigned': 87,
          'Files Loaded': 1595},
 'Red': {'Discrepancies Identified': 1606,
         'Files Analyzed': 59,
         'Files Assigned': 1510,
         'Files Loaded': 110},
 'Yellow': {'Discrepancies Identified': 47,
            'Files Analyzed': 1238,
            'Files Assigned': 1253,
            'Files Loaded': 4285}}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help